# How to programmatically create new browser sessions in IE every time a user accessed an application URL in new browser window

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom-events

How to programmatically create new browser sessions in IE every time a user accessed an application URL in new browser window? This is similar to simulating the manual action “File->New Session” menu in IE8 or IE9.

Our users want to login to our application in multiple independent sessions in different IE windows and do independent actions. Since, IE maintains common browser cache to access auth details, new browser window will  continue with the existing session without creating a new session. We do not want to invalidate previous session of a user while creating new session for same user to ensure both sessions are active.

Answer (score 3):

I personally would not try to fight the default session behavior of the browser, but would rather have the application handle separate parallel sub-sessions.  So, if a user in one session wanted to open a new session, you could perhaps open a new tab, with sub-session id passed in URL parameters.  You could then propagate each subsession by passing along the subsession information.