# Open browser window using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser

To open a new IE browser window, I'm using below code.

```
window.open ("http://jsc.simfatic-solutions.com","mywindow");
```

But how can I open a new IE window with **new Session** ?

Comment: In IE file menu there is an option called open new session.

Comment: In that case, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14508473/how-to-programmatically-create-new-browser-sessions-in-ie-every-time-a-user-acce) is a duplicate, with an answer along the same lines as @Quentin's below - ie use subsessions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sessions are generally handled via cookies, and there is no way to programatically make a browser start a new cookiejar for a window.

You will need to provide some other session tracking mechanism. One way to do this is via a URL parameter (e.g. `?SESSION_ID=123455`). This has security implications (because session ids can leak through link sharing and referers) but [PHP has native support](https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.use-trans-sid) for it.

You would probably be better off using a regular session and then have a sub-session within it. Store all your data in `$_SESSION['subsession'][0]` and then pass the numerical id through the query string.

Comment: Thanks for yur answer. How can I open a subsession with new window?

Comment: `window.open("/newsubsession");` and then redirect to `/somepage?subsession=2` with a `Location:` header.

Comment: Should it be done on the server side logic? can it be done on the client side?

Comment: You can't tell the server that it needs to store data in a different box without using server side code.